# changed file permissions not taking effect

Tags: wordpress, permissions

my installed wordpress theme is loading css from wp-content/uploads/tc_stylesheets/file_name.css

This file needs to be writable and executable so that whenever I change theme settings ( especially styles related changes ) from customizer, the changes are written to that css file ( file_name.css ).

Even after changing the relevant directory permissions to 777, the message in theme dashboard, still saying `" Can not write file with chmod: 0, owner/group: root/root"`

I'm not allowed to post images yet, so here is what I did

> > changed permission of uploads dir to 777
> >
> > changed permission of tc_stylesheets dir to 777
> >
> > changed the file_name.css file permission to 777

as I already stated above these changes still not implementing i.e., whenever I apply new css rules, file is still the same.

Theme appends a unique number in the file_name.css ( e.g., file_name.123456.css ) whenever there is change in style rules from the customizer.

( Note: I asked same issue in the theme support, they didn't reply either that's why I asked here. If anyone has encountered this issue before, please any help would be appreciated )

Comment: Never use 777 for a website file permission (unless real reason). 755 as @SergioS said is better. It's possible that your file have "root" ownership, but your webserver/php do not run under root (usually www-data or nginx-fpm). Check on which user your webserver/php is running, and chown those files to this user and chmod 755.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track with the folder permissions. (Though i'd strongly advise you to change the owner/group and use 755 instead.)

Still, you don't mention the permissions of the file itself, which in your case would need to be 666.